# Design pattern to use for Null check through Reflection

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, annotations

What we are doing - Annotation driven null and empty values check for Object.

How we are doing - Creating one annotation and putting that annotation on the variable declaration.

> I am not sure what design pattern i need to use to make it work best

. Please suggest.

Annotation class -

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface Test {


/**
 * Message.
 *
 * @return the string
 */
public String message();

}
```

How we are declaring variable -

```
@Test(message="five message")
private String five;
```

How i am calling annotation processor -

```
    Class<?> annotationClass = annotationTestinClass.getClass();
    Field[] decalaredFieldsArray = annotationClass.getDeclaredFields();
    List<String> lstString = new ArrayList<>();
    parseFields(decalaredFieldsArray,annotationTestinClass,lstString);
```

How i am processing object -

```
    public static List<String> parseFields(Field[] decalaredFieldsArray,Object obj,List<String> lstString){

    Arrays.stream(decalaredFieldsArray).forEach(field ->{
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Test test = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(Test.class);
        if(field.getType().isPrimitive() || field.getType().getName().equals("java.lang.String")){
            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)){
                try {
                    System.out.println("field value is :"+field.get(obj));
                    System.out.println("field Name is :"+field.getName());
                    if(field.get(obj)== null || !StringUtils.isNoneBlank(field.get(obj).toString())){
                        lstString.add(test.message());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else{
            Field[] objectFields =null;
            Object objValue = null;
            try {
                if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)){
                    objValue = field.get(obj);
                    if(objValue!=null){
                        objectFields = objValue.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                        parseFields(objectFields, objValue, lstString);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Object value is -"+field.get(obj));
                        System.out.println("Messsage value is -"+test.message());
                        lstString.add(test.message());
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
    return lstString;
}
```

Here Test.Class is repersenting my Test annotation.

Comment: If you annotate the variable at the declaration - at which point in time do you want to check for null? Right at the declaration? Every second sunday? What part of the code is supposed to call/execute that check?

Comment: Try Null Object  Pattern: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/null_object_pattern.htm

Comment: Is `Optional` an option?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis that pattern forces you to subclass a specific class, which is bad. It also has nothing to do with the annotations that OP requires.

Comment: @F1sh we are using this code in jar to check the passed request object values i.e we are processing annotation in that jar. I know we have lots of annotation available in spring to check this but those will be fired at run time only, kindly correct me if i am wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations don't work that way.

You can create custom annotations that get processed at compile time. But at compile time, very often, you might not be able to check that

```
@NotNull
private Whatever foo = someBar();
```

really leads to "not null". In other words: at compile time, no code behind @NotNull can really decide in all cases if the annotated variable will be really not null.

And at runtime, annotations ... are just that: Meta-Information!
Meaning: if you want annotations to have an effect at runtime, you need code that checks for annotations when doing things.

Example: you create @Persist.

And then you have a framework that "processes objects". And whenever that framework **processes** some object, it can check if that annotation is present, and if so "persist" that object.

In other words:

```
foo = bar;
```

will just assign bar to foo; and there is "no framework" in place that could check if foo is @NotNull annotated, and do something about that assignment if bar is null.

So, in order for you to be helpful, you need

1. That new annotation
2. Some sort of "processor" that works on objects; and checks if they are annotated; and if they are annotated, special things happen.

Comment: Thanks GhostCat!!! We have created our own annotation only but i am not sure about the design approach. Could you please help me in that as well.

Comment: See my last update: the point is - such an annotation only makes sense if you have **framework**-like code.